# How to animate 120 images efficiently?

Tags: iphone, animation

There are 120 images which are 360-degree round shootings of a product showcase, each is 3 degree apart, size 320 x 320 pixels. Displaying the images continuously will give the effect of rotating the product in front of the user.

So far, the performance is far from satisfactory, there is delay in loading and when the user touch to slide to a particular image.

If OpenGL is not an option, what is the recommended way to handle this kind of animation efficiently? Thanks!

Comment: What are you currently using for animation? If you are only showing one image at a time it would be very surprising to me that you are using core animation

Comment: @Rudiger I simply display those `UIImage`s now.

Comment: I don't understand, if your just displaying an UIImage, where is the animation?

Comment: The animation is in the point of view of the user. Rotating among the images will show different angles of the product to the user.

Comment: Have you consider the way that I've suggested, using HTML5 on a UIWebView?

Comment: @vfn I am not familiar with HTML5 so I'll try it as last resort.

Comment: It's the most simple way to do what you want. You can use the sample from Apple.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really understand your UI but here is my guess:

- Your UI is a circle contains a lots of images and all are in the same screen. I think you can show the thumbnail images (50x50-80x80) in the circle and you can store all of thumbnails in memory without big issue. With that size, each of them is just around 8kb. 120 x 9 ~ 1 MB of memory
- When you animate to an image, you can load the thumbnail first and then loading the big image in the background. It will create some effects that user see some images not clear and then see it clear. This will also help when users touch some to slide to a particular image. At least, you have something to show.
- You can save some memory and loading issue by resizing the big image to be 75-80% of the size 320x320. This one will save you a little bit of time for loading the images and doesn't impact the image's quality a lot. It all depends on your app as well.
- You can try to use eager loading. You can load images ahead before you actually animate them. You can have an array to store 3 - 5 images (320 x 320 is not a big size, so 5 of them will just around 500-1000 KB). When you show the first image, you start loading the 4 th image before hand.

Comment: I think you can still keep all thumbnail images in the memory and then show it first. Another way is eager loading as I tell you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to really compress this and have smooth playback on mobile, you should store it as a movie and then use AVFoundation's AVPlayer to have custom playback.  You can set it to roughly any frame or change the speed of playback forward or backward and loop to make it seamless.  You could, for example, set it up to change the location or play velocity in the movie based on a swipe.  It is more work to set up than MPMoviePlayer but is quite customizable.

Answer (score 1):

How about a UIWebView + HTML5?

Look at the apple showcase: http://www.apple.com/html5/showcase/threesixty/

Answer (score 1):

I would make lowres copies of all 120 images, maybe 80x80 in size.  All 120 should fit in the GPU's texture cache.  Load all 120 images into 120 offscreen image views, zoomed up to 320x320.  Animate using those 120 image views, showing one image at a time.  Whenever the animation stops, quickly replace the last image with one more view that has the corresponding full resolution 320x320 copy.  Whenever the user starts to start to animation, switch back to the lowres set of images.

This works because the eye can't see changing objects (illusion of motion) with the same resolution as they can a static image, depending on the rate of animation of course.